# iPhone full Backup possible?

Tags: iphone, backup

I am updating my iPhone from a 6 to 8.
I wanted to move everything including passwords from the old phone, and I understood that I needed to perform an encrypted backup.

The file is 23.33GB vs the 53GB storage used on my phone. Is the file compressed to account for this or does the full backup not include everything on the iPhone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full backup does not include:

- iOS itself (since that will already be on the other device),
- app bundles (since they will be downloaded from the App Store again).

App data *is* backed up even if the apps themselves aren't. It's as full of a backup as is available and will back up all of your data.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson App bundles download from the App Store through itunes.apple.com, there’s no iCloud interoperation and you don’t even need to be logged into iCloud. Are you thinking of ‘iTunes in the Cloud’ being an iCloud service? Not sure what you’re referring to with Apple Pay and cards?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @grg answer, backups do not include Media Library (iBooks, iTunes purchases, music, podcasts). Also, app developers decide what to include in the backup, so it would be good to save all important data manually first if it's saved in some app.

p.s. Apps that store sensitive data (like 1Password) usually store it in keychain, so make sure to make an encrypted backup (even with some easy pass like '12345').